# Error message Argument 'angularCrud' is not a function, got undefined in MVC4 with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am developing small Crud operation application in MVC4 with angularJS. I am getting error message as below.

```
Argument 'angularCrud' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am refering below article.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1032226/CRUD-Operation-in-ASP-NET-MVC-and-AngularJS
```

This is my controller code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetAllGroups()
        {
            using (C3KYCEntities db = new C3KYCEntities())
            {

                var groupList = db.tm_grp_group.ToList();
                return Json(groupList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

This is my view code.

```
<div ng-controller="angularCrud">
    <div ng-app="angularCrud">
        <div class="divList">
            <p><b><i>Group List</i></b></p>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>ID</b></td>
                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Desc</b></td>
                    <td><b>IsActive</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="group in groups">
                    <td>
                        {{group.grp_id}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{group.grp_name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{group.grp_description}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{group.grp_isactive}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span ng-click="editgroup(group)" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</span>
                        <span ng-click="deletegroup(group)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</span>
                    </td>

                </tr>
           </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my Module.js

```
var app = angular.module('angularCrud',[]);
```

This is my Service.js

```
app.service("crudAJService", function ($http) {
    alert("Hi");
    this.getGroups = function () {
        return $http.get("Home/GetAllGroups");
    };
```

Here my alert is not firng.
This is my controller code.

```
app.controller("angularCrud", function ($scope, crudAJService) {
    $scope.divGroup = false;
    alert("Hi");
    GetAllGroups();
    function GetAllGroups() {
        var getGroupData = crudAJService.getGroups();
        getGroupData.then(function (group) {
            alert("Hi");
            $scope.groups = group.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting group records');
        }
        );
    }

});
```

I stuck in Module.js. Execution will not go further and I am getting error as Argument 'angularCrud' is not a function, got undefined. Can someone tell me Where I am going wrong in the above code? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your module name rather than having same name for controller and module,

```
var app = angular.module('Crud',[]);
```

Also ng-controller should come after ng-app

```
<div ng-app="Crud">
  <div ng-controller="angularCrud">
```

Comment: are you sure? can i get team viewer?